# launchd, how to run a command every 3 minutes, during working hours on a weekday?

Tags: terminal, command-line, launchd, cron, macos

I know `cron` and that is fairly simple

`*/3 9-17 * * 1-5 myCommand`

How does one do the same in launchd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR Summary: `launchd` is "better" than `cron` in many ways, but these sorts of repetitions are an example of one way where `cron` is easier than `launchd`. [To do this in `launchd` is excessively verbose](https://gist.github.com/tjluoma/0f81bb814e576da9a01390c34a353ed0). (That link will take you to a gist because it is literally too long to post to StackExchange.)

[Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) supports cron-style execution times. If I wanted to run something using cron's time formats, I would definitely use Keyboard Maestro.

There is an extremely helpful and friendly forum available at https://forum.keyboardmaestro.com where users (and the developer of Keyboard Maestro) are available to help.

[nohillside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/nohillside) made an excellent point that the easiest way to do this in `launchd` is to run a script every 3 minutes, but check at the beginning of that script whether or not it is within the desired times.

Save the script below as `/usr/local/bin/mycommand.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh -f
# Purpose: Run a command, but only between certain hours, on certain days
#
# From: Timothy J. Luoma
# Mail: luomat at gmail dot com
# Date: 2021-02-23

    # this assumes your work-day starts at 9am
    # adjust as needed
START_HOUR='9'

    # this assumes that your work day stops at 5pm (1700 hours)
    # adjust as needed
STOP_HOUR='17'

    # adjust if needed
PATH='/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin'

NAME="$0:t:r"

    # needed for 'strftime'
zmodload zsh/datetime

    # this will check the current day of the week
DAY_OF_WEEK=`strftime "%a" "$EPOCHSECONDS"`

    # change the days listed if you
    # take off different days than Saturday or Sunday
case "$DAY_OF_WEEK" in
    Sat|Sun)
            # note that we do not want to use 'exit 1'
            # because `launchd` will interpret that
            # as a reason not to continue to run
            # this script in the future
            # which we do not want

        echo "$NAME: '$DAY_OF_WEEK' is not a work day." >>/dev/stderr
        exit 0
    ;;

esac

    # check what hour it is: 0-23
CURRENT_HOUR=`strftime "%H" "$EPOCHSECONDS"`

    # compare current hour with starting hour
if [[ "$CURRENT_HOUR" -lt "$START_HOUR" ]]
then
        echo "$NAME: '$CURRENT_HOUR' is before the start of the work day ($START_HOUR)." >>/dev/stderr
        exit 0

    # compare current hour with stopping hour
elif [[ "$CURRENT_HOUR" -gt "$STOP_HOUR" ]]
then
        echo "$NAME: '$CURRENT_HOUR' is after the end of the work day ($START_HOUR)." >>/dev/stderr
        exit 0
fi

##################################################################
###
### If we get here, it is between the appropriate hours on the appropriate day,
### and the commands below here should be executed.
###

echo "Hello World"

exit 0
```

Make sure the script is executable:

`chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/mycommand.sh`

Then save this (below) as `~/Library/LaunchAgents/local.mycommand.plist` (you can call it whatever you want, just make sure that it ends with `.plist`. Also, you may have to create that folder if it does not exist).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>local.mycommand</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/usr/local/bin/mycommand.sh</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/local.mycommand.stderr.txt</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/local.mycommand.stdout.txt</string>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>180</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Give it sane permissions:

`chmod 644 ~/Library/LaunchAgents/local.mycommand.plist`

Then either log out/log in, or just run this command:

`launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/local.mycommand.plist`

Errors that the script generate will be saved to `/tmp/local.mycommand.stderr.txt`

Other output will be saved to `/tmp/local.mycommand.stdout.txt`

You can change that by editing the paths in the `.plist`.

## Conclusion

[Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) is one of the best apps ever made for the Mac, and I think anyone who wants to do any kind of automation on the Mac should own it. This is a perfect example of just one way that it makes things easier than using `cron` (because it's easier to debug) or `launchd` because it's easier to use and invoke it when you want, even for power users who know things like `launchd` and `cron`.

The only regret I've ever had about Keyboard Maestro was not starting to use it sooner in my life. (I'm just a user of the app, not connected to it in any other way, and I *{GLADLY!}* pay for the app out of my own pocket, so I'm not getting paid anything by anyone to say anything.)

Comment: Thanks for the long answer. And +1 for Keyboard Maestro!

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to implement timed jobs in launchd is the key `StartCalendarInterval`. Unfortunately the syntax is rather verbose:

```
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>9</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>9</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>3</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
        ...
    </array>
```

In your specific case this amounts to 900 `dict` entries.

The launchd GUI [LaunchControl](https://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/) generates this configuration from cron-style time specifications:

[image]

It also allows for importing/exporting of jobs from/to crontab.